# Выбор контроллера для вкладок IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Есть приложение, с вкладками, в каждой вкладке - edittext-ы, checkbox, и т.д. приложение создано для android, и теперь хочу сделать так же для IOS.
Суть вопроса - с помощью чего это лучше сделать? какой контроллер лучше использовать?

Варианты: tab bar controller(есть минусы, т.к. надо сделать общую кнопку для всех вкладок, и нужен свайп между табами), segmentedcontrol или PageViewController?

Скрины приложения на android
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется в вашей ситуации лучше использовать для каждого вида свой `UIViewController` или `UITableViewController`. Все это поместить в `Conteiner View Controller`, а его в свою очередь на `UIViewController` где будут отрабатываться нажатия кнопок (табов) и анимация. Удобней будет поддерживать таблицы по отдельности, чем делать все в одном месте и создавать массивный контроллер.

Comment: Так и делаю, переключаюсь между viewcontroller-ами при помощи Segmented Control

Comment: @YuraGeyts может есть решение?